# Why do outsiders have trouble pronouncing the "v" sounds in Gerudo words?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

[image: Lyndae the Goron, saying: "Er... Sa...botta? Was that it? I can't tell... Apparently you really have to bite your lip to get that V sound out clearly."]
([images source video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyi2rl0OaIE), 7:32-7:36)

This Goron in Gerudo Town is having trouble pronouncing "sav'otta", Gerudo for "good morning", going as far to state an inability to tell the difference between V and B sounds. Several other non-natives talk about the various Vs in multiple Gerudo words ("sav'aaq", "sav'saaba", "voe", etc.) being tricky at best.

But in the same utterance, there's clearly no trouble with "have" or "V sound". And the letter V isn't exactly rare in English.

What's the inconsistency here about?

Comment: *Are* they speaking English?

Comment: Maybe the 'v' in Gerudo has a particular sound, distinct from English 'v' or 'b'. Maybe Gorons have issues with the Gerudo language. Maybe there's no such thing as English and they're all speaking Hylian, the game devs just decided to write things in English to make it easier for you to understand. Maybe this is just a throwaway line to add some background flavor to the world and you're thinking about this too hard.

Comment: My guess is that it's related to Japanese. Since there is no "v" in Japanese, they use "b" instead. For instance, the "Velvet Room" in the Persona series is pronounced like "Belubetto loomoo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a carry-over reference from the original Japanese script.  Natural Japanese doesn't have a 'v' sound.  They use the 'b' series of katakana to represent it.   As a result, many Japanese people have a hard time saying the 'v' sound and default to the 'b' (i.e. television in Japanese is 'terebi').

Read more in this Q & A:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24498/do-japanese-actually-pronounce-the-v-sound

Answer (score 0):

The Gerudo pronunciation in this case might be similar to traditional Spanish, where the letter 'v' is pronounced more like a soft 'b'. It's not that he can't pronounce the 'v' sounds you're imagining, he can't pronounce the sound that the Gerudo/Spanish make instead. To get an idea of what the Goron means, try saying 'b'-words without letting your lips firmly touch and "explode" out, like they normally would when pronouncing a 'b'. This can be difficult for a lot of native English speakers, as it's not really a sound that we normally make.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a language expert, I studied Spanish for a couple of years and this is what I was taught. Since the Gerudo have other Spanish influences, I thought this language characteristic might be taken from them as well.

Comment: It seems like what he's saying could apply to English as well.  He mentions "biting his lip" to make the sound.  When you make a "b" sound, your lips only touch each other.  When you make a "v" (or at least when I do) I have to touch my teeth to my bottom lip.  It may be that they find it weird how they have to use their teeth to pronounce the sound they aren't used to (also not a language expert).

Answer (score -1):

While this is definitely a problem with exposure (those who were  raised to pronounce these words can do so better than those who haven't), it is entirely possible this is a **physiological** issue due to biology.

While everyone is capable, keep in mind that the Gerudo are completely different races from Hylians, Gorons, Rito and Zora; from body shape to facial features: key biological differences. Gerudo are not just used to forming their own words, but may actually be capable of better pronunciation accuracy for their words than the other races.  Rito have beaks, so forming words that aren't easy without lips can be tough (though, given that some real-world birds are excellent mimics, perhaps not).  Gorons in particular, have extremely wide faces and mouths, so it might be tougher for them to create an appropriate 'v' sound over the other three non-Gerudo races.

Comment: Nice downvote without a reason.

Comment: @Broneironaut - all the answers are going negative.  They're all good answers in my opinion.  Must be the "hot" exposure